# paperclip resize not working for dynamic columns on attachment model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have a two columns on my attachment model on which the user sets the dimension to which they want to resize the image.

However, the variables when the resize happens are nil, but set to actual values after the resize happens.

below is the code

```
  has_attached_file :file, :styles => lambda { |a|
                          { :logo => ["200x50>",:png],
                            :user_defined => ["#{a.instance.custom_width}x#{a.instance.custom_height}>",:png] }
                        }
```

**`the custom_width & custom_height are nil when conversion happens however the logo conversion works as expected.`**

**`I am using ruby 2.2.4p230 & Rails 4.2.4`**

below is the full mode code

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model_one

  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true
  #has_attached_file :file, styles: { logo: ['200x50>',:png] }
  has_attached_file :file, styles: lambda { |attachment| attachment.instance.styles }

  def styles
    Rails.logger.info self.inspect
    Rails.logger.info self.attachable
    styles = {}
    m = "200x50>"
    l = "#{self.custom_width}x#{self.custom_height}>"
    styles[:logo] = [m, :png]
    styles[:user_defined] = [l, :png]
    styles
  end

end
```

Can anyone please help and let me know if i am doing something wrong?

Comment: can you copy the full model code ? and where do you get custom_width from ? is it a column in database, an attr accessor ... ? you can try `self.custom_width` instead

Comment: Its a column on the attachment model

Comment: just now added full model code

Comment: I am not used to adding styles in function so can't comment on that. But I am not too sure if you can put `#` anywhee else but at the end like `250x250#`. You may have to chose between `>` and `#`

Comment: # & > are two different ways of resizing